# authentication failed from httpinterface and Robomongo

Tags: mongodb

**edit:**

Ah bad news, Robomongo 0.8.x doesn't support SCRAM-SHA-1
 https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/766. Good news is that V0.9 they're working hard with promises support for it.

And also the http interface in Mongo 3.0 doesn't work with SCRAM-SHA-1 user documents, because "(it) is generally considered insecure".
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17527

---

I've just set up a mongo3.0 replica set, and enabled authentication, and created an userAdminAnyDatabase admin and a normal readWrite user.

```
./mongod --dbpath=/usr/local/mongo/mongodb/data/data1 --logpath=/usr/local/mongo/mongodb/logs/log1/mongodb.log --port 27017 --replSet jv_mongo --smallfiles --fork --rest --httpinterface --keyFile /usr/local/mongo/mongodb/key/mongodb.pem 
./mongod --dbpath=/usr/local/mongo/mongodb/data/data2 --logpath=/usr/local/mongo/mongodb/logs/log2/mongodb.log --port 27018 --replSet jv_mongo --smallfiles --fork --rest --httpinterface --keyFile /usr/local/mongo/mongodb/key/mongodb.pem
./mongod --dbpath=/usr/local/mongo/mongodb/data/data3 --logpath=/usr/local/mongo/mongodb/logs/log3/mongodb.log --port 27019 --replSet jv_mongo --smallfiles --fork --rest --httpinterface --keyFile /usr/local/mongo/mongodb/key/mongodb.pem


jv_mongo:PRIMARY> use admin
switched to db admin
jv_mongo:PRIMARY> db.getUser("mongoAdmin");
{
    "_id" : "admin.mongoAdmin",
    "user" : "mongoAdmin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}

jv_mongo:PRIMARY> use comment
switched to db comment
jv_mongo:PRIMARY> db.getUser("comment");
{
    "_id" : "comment.comment",
    "user" : "comment",
    "db" : "comment",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "comment"
        }
    ]
}
```

And access the shell without any problem.

```
./mongo --port 27017 -u mongoAdmin -p PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase admin

./mongo --port 27017 -u comment -p PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase comment

jv_mongo:PRIMARY> db.user_login.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5506a9de41e1073435ff06b3"), "id" : NumberLong(2), "user_id" : 9527, "login_time" : ISODate("2015-03-16T10:01:02.378Z"), "login_ip" : "127.0.0.1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5506a9de41e1073435ff06b4"), "id" : NumberLong(3), "user_id" : 9538, "login_time" : ISODate("2015-03-16T10:01:02.380Z"), "login_ip" : "127.0.0.1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5506a9de41e1073435ff06b5"), "id" : NumberLong(4), "user_id" : 9549, "login_time" : ISODate("2015-03-16T10:01:02.382Z"), "login_ip" : "127.0.0.1" }
```

And also successfully accessed mongo via java driver

[image]

**But** I received auth fail when trying **Robomongo** or **192.168.106.152:28017**.
[image: Robomongo]

[image: http interface]

I'm not very familiar with Mongo or Mongo3.0, maybe I'm missing some key configuration?

Comment: Robomongo (as at 0.8.5) does not yet support the new SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication in MongoDB 3.0: https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/766

Comment: For any other interface "prebuilt install" the same reasoning is in place in that the "driver" used by that application does not support the updated authentication methods. So for your "favorite tools", check in for updates of when the driver integration will be in place. Alternately, "please contribute" with your alterations to "make it work". For every tool available, we would appreciate the contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Use [MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/download/), it will work for mongodb 3.0+